# Bool method returns wrong value

Tags: c++, boolean, return-value, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I created a `bool contains(string)` method for a linked list hash table which checks if a value is in the hash. I use a helper function to recurse, but when the helper function returns `false`, the `bool contains(string)` still returns true. I ran it through the debugger and I can clearly see that it returns false, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the current node being searched:

`"laccoliths"->"morbiferous"->"oculi"->"unscabbarded"`

the value I'm searching for is `"typung"`.

Here's the code:

```
bool contains_h(string x, node * p) //helper method
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return false;
    else if (x == p->data)
        return true;
    else
        contains_h(x, p->next);
}
```

`bool contains(string word) { return contains_h(word, head); }`

Comment: Enabling compiler warnings (and reading them) would have prevented this mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice simple one. You forgot to put 'return' on the final statement:

```
bool contains_h(string x, node * p) //helper method
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return false;
    else if (x == p->data)
        return true;
    else
        return contains_h(x, p->next);
}
```

---

And out of curiosity, I rewrote your code to a one-liner to see what it would look like:

```
bool contains_h(string x, node * p) //helper method
{
    return ((p!=NULL) && (x == p->data || contains_h(x, p->next)));
}
```

Personally, I would prefer to read your six lines. However, others might disagree, particularly because it would have avoided the missing return statement problem.